# React Native: read sub collections' title from firestore(firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code to read the listNames which are collections but as you see I have specified them as a constant array but i want the code to retrieve them dynamically:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const { route } = this.props;
      const { restaurantId } = route.params;

      const db = getFirestore(app);

      const listNames = ["CakeList", "FoodList", "DrinkList"];

      const dataPromises = listNames.map(async (listName) => {
        const listRef = collection(
          db,
          `birthday/${restaurantId}/menu/menuItems/${listName}`
        );
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(listRef);
        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        return { title: listName, data: data };
      });

      const data = await Promise.all(dataPromises);
      this.setState({ data });
    
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error fetching restaurant photos:", error);
    }
  }
```

hree is a sample of my structure which might help:

```
birthday-(collection)
        -restaurantId(sub-collection)
                    - menu(collection)
                          -menuItems(sub-collection)
                                 -cakeList(collection)
                                         cakeName:name
                                         cakePrice:4555
                                         cakeSpecification:""
                                 -foodList(collection)
                                         foodName:name
                                         foodPrice:4555
                                         foodSpecification:""
                                 -drinkList(collection)

                                 ..etc
```

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it.

Comment: The client-side SDKs for Firestore don't have an API to list collections. The typical solution is to store the value from the `listNames` you now have in your code in the parent document, and then read it from there.